# Footer doesn't get down by sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I was creating a theme for wp, and there is a problem.
I have a div with class: footer:

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="link-posts"><!--NEW POSTS-->
   <div class="new-posts">مطالب جدید</div>
</div>  
<div class="div-posts">
   <ul class="ul-posts">
      <li class="li-posts"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=8#posts" class="a-posts"></a>
      <a class="a-posts" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=39">امیر محمد احمدی</a><br>                                <a class="a-posts" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=34">یبذیبذیبذ</a><br>                                
      <a class="a-posts" href="./FILE_files/FILE.htm">رفت آن سوار</a><br>                                           <a class="a-posts" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=6">jsjjjjjj</a><br>                              
      <a class="a-posts" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=4">تست</a><br>
      <a class="a-posts" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=1">سلام دنیا!</a><br>
      </li>
    </ul>   
</div>  
<div class="Latest-Comments">
   <div class="comments">آخرین نظرات</div>
</div>
<div class="div-comments">
   <ul class="ul-comments">
     <li class="li-comments">
     <ul>
       <li><strong><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=1#comment-1" title="on سلام دنیا!">آقای وردپرس</a></strong>: سلام،‌ این نوشته یک «دیدگاه» است. برای پاک کردن یا ویرایش ی...</li>
     </ul>
     </li>              
   </ul>
</div>      
<div class="Archive">
   <div class="amir-archive">پربازدیدترین نوشته ها</div>
</div>  
<div class="div-archive">
   <ul class="ul-archive">
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=8#archive" class="a-archive"></a>
    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=8#archive" class="a-archive"></a>
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=34" title="یبذیبذیبذ">یبذیبذیبذ</a> - 0 views</li>
    <li><a href="./FILE_files/FILE.htm" title="رفت آن سوار">رفت آن سوار</a> - 0 views</li><li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?p=39" title="امیر محمد احمدی">امیر محمد احمدی</a> - 0 views</li>                 
  </ul> 
  <div class="Copyright">
     <div class="hoghogh">-1392©&nbsp;حقوق مطالب ،تصاویر و طرح قالب برای نام سایت محفوظ است.</div><div class="time-copy">۱۳۹۳</div>
  </div>
  </div>        
</div>
<!--/LOGIN-->
```

and there is two different divs sister this div which are all under a parent container.

the problem is there footer doesn't get down based on sidebar's size, it just does this with the posts' size.

there is a container for the sidebar, float: left; a container for posts, float: right and the footer is clear: both.

helps are welcome :D

the files are uploaded here: http://up.ashiyane.org/images/n1k6iu0xsd0k3elni4hy.zip

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your sidebar and posts with another div and add that div clearfix class, for example

```
<div id="main_container" class="clearfix">    
<div="second_container" class="clearfix"> <--add this
<div id="posts_cnt" class="clearfix">
</div>
<div class="container-sidebar clearfix">
</div>
</div><--add this
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it, the problem persists... :(

Comment: a closing div was missing in my original code. Can you make sure you have proper closing divs?